# mlt melt slideshow with audio is not playing sound

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, melt, mlt, melt-framework

I am trying to run a melt/mlt command and so far it seems to work EXCEPT there's no audio sound being played. I know the audio track is being added because the length of the video. Here's what I have --

```
melt \
placeholder.png length=200 \
inside.png length=200 \
placeholder.png length=200 \
-track waltz.mp3 -transition mix \
-consumer avformat:"output.mp4"
```

Not sure why but the video does not have any sound

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by specifying an audio codec and a video codec in the last line:

```
-consumer avformat:"output.mp4" acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264
```